How can I automatically generate unit test cases for a Spring Boot project?
Is there any way to automatically generate test cases for:

Service layer
Repository layer (with mocking or real DB connections)
Controller layer (including MockMvc)

I came across some tools like Spring Boot Test Starter, but it seems focused on testing setup rather than automatic test generation.
I’m looking for something that can:

Generate basic test cases (boilerplate code) for existing methods.
Work well with existing annotations like @Service, @Repository, and @RestController.
Integrate with JUnit 5 and Mockito, as I am using them in my project.

Are there any tools, libraries, or techniques that can help automate this process, or at least speed up the creation of unit tests?
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

"Seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers." -> off-topic. Besides, what would be the point of auto-generated tests? You want to test your logic and a code-generation tool couldn't possibly know what you want to test.

You don't trust your own code, but would trust auto-generated code of a third-party? GPT of choice would be an answer.

There is a tool called webship-js is an Automated Functional Acceptance Testing tool. Helps to ease and speed up the work with the End-to-end testing features in web apps or projects. Using Nightwatch.js and Cucumber-js. Having custom and advanced general step definitions.
visite webship.co site

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
